# redux store returns only null value. checked at reducer, the reducer returns actual data, but the combinereducer doesnot

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Reducers/Reduer_placeorder.js

```
export default function(state =[], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "PLACE_ORDER":
          console.log("inside reducer")
          console.log(action.payload)//returns data that is passed
      return action.payload;


    default: 
          console.log("default")
          return state;
  }
}
```

> here it returns the actual payload

Reducers/index.js

```
import { combineReducers} from "redux";
import reducer_placeorder from "./Reducer_placeorder";


const rootReducer  = combineReducers({
  data:reducer_placeorder,


})
console.log("inside combine reducer")
export default rootReducer;
```

> reducer_placeorder does not contains the data,

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import 'semantic-ui-css/semantic.min.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {createStore} from  'redux';
import rootReducer  from './Reducers';


const store = createStore(rootReducer);
console.log("the state from store")
console.log(store.getState());
   *//returns {data: []}** not getting the passes data*
ReactDOM.render((
  <BrowserRouter><Provider store={store}><App /></Provider></BrowserRouter>
), document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

> not getting the data stored..return only null array
>
> { data: []  }**
>   not getting the passed state

Comment: You are logging store.getState() before you action might be called or even the update is done in redux store. You should log the redux state in App component

Comment: Sorry I ahave not copied the complete code here.
i called this.props.dispatch(reducer_action_placeorder(data)) from container and used 
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ reducer_action_placeorder: reducer_action_placeorder }, dispatch);
}
**in container

Comment: got solved, there was a mistake in browserrouter. thanks  you